# How to make an Internet connection status Event listener in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

ive been searching google about how to make an internet connection status event listener on c#. Does anyone knows how to do this? Have seen network change, but its just checking the network and not the internet connection status (if connected, or disconnected)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, how do you define connected vs disconnected when you're talking about the internet? What exactly should you be able to access if you're connected?

Comment: @itsme86 im making a client server application (desktop app), and i need to make an event listener of internet status to see if there's an active internet. if disconnected i need to prompt the client that the internet connection is disconnected or not available.